# Pipeline Input/Output

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I want to list the files of C: drive. First of all, I want to get the device ID from logical disk wmi object, and list it.

**Below command returns:**

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_logicaldisk


DeviceID     : C:  
DriveType    : 3  
ProviderName :  
FreeSpace    : 940371968  
Size         : 125809192960  
VolumeName   :
```

**But this command:**

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_logicaldisk | select deviceid | Get-ChildItem -path {$_}
```

gives below error:

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name
>   '@{deviceid=C' does not exist.   At line:1 char:60
>   + Get-WmiObject -class Win32_logicaldisk | select deviceid | Get-ChildItem -path { ...
>   +                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{deviceid=C:String) [Get-ChildItem], DriveNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem -path accepts pipeline input, how we can solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Select` is returning an Object with a property named DeviceID.

Use `-ExpandProperty` to get the property value, then pipe that:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_logicaldisk | select -expandproperty deviceid | Get-ChildItem -path {$_}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also just select the property in the Object that gets returned. In this case, `$_.DeviceID`

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_logicaldisk | select deviceid | Get-ChildItem -path {$_.DeviceID}
```